WIFI not working on iMac Early 2008 with LTS 24.04
I installed Ubuntu on an old iMac Early 2008. Its running well except that the WIFI doesnt work. Ive done the following to try and fix the issue
The WIFI card is a broadcom BCM4321 (Airport Extreme), additional drivers shows 1 proprietary driver in use. Tried reinstalling this, same issue.
Ran
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer

Same issue.
I followed the instructions on this page
"No Wi-Fi Adapter Found", Ubuntu 22.04, Broadcom Wireless Drivers [14e4:4331] (rev 02) MacBook Pro
I downloaded the file and extracted it to my desktop, then ran the terminal commands
cd /usr/lib/firmware
sudo cp ~/Desktop/b43fw_508/b43/*  b43
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43

I left out mkdir 43 as I was getting an error message that it already existed.
I then ran the following commands instead of the ones listed on the page above because the terminal didn't like the reinstall command.
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer

The WIFI comes back immediately after doing this, but if I restart, it then things go back to square one.
Does anyone know how to permanently fix the Wi-Fi? Thanks in advance.

I question the need for 24.04 on such an old machine. I would install 22.04, then install the broadcom driver separately. also, consider the Mint 22 release.

I installed LTS 24.04 on an iMac A1224 (2008) and ran into the same problem as you described. By doing a fresh install and choosing NOT to install 3rd party drivers during installation, and then following the same instructions as you referred to, the WiFi is working.
You cannot leave out "mkdir 43" in this case, instead follow the original instructions.

Ich kann das Problem nicht bestätigen. Broadcom Wlan Treiber wird unter Anwendungen & Aktualisierungen - zusätzliche Treiber installiert. Bei mir wird die Karte erkannt - Treiber eingebunden - und das Wlan Netzwerkmenü angezeigt. Funktioniert problemlos. Das Verwenden eines LAN Kabels ist angeraten... einer Ethernetverbindung zum Router.
Jedoch kann ich ein Problem mit dem Bereitschaftsmodus beklagen. Nach dem Aufwachen ist der Bildschirm milchig weiß - und nur ein Neustart verhilft zu einem verwendbaren system - Graka - Radeon.
